# TeraGSS Security Library - Exception occurred in TERAGSS layer: The token failed the integrity check

Tags: .net, odbc, teradata

I am using .NET Provider (Teradata.Client.Provider) and Teradata 17.2 to run some jobs that pulls data from Teradata into my SQL database, I get following error:

`Tables loading of which failed: TABLE_1, TABLE_2, TABLE_3. System.AggregateException: One of more errors occurred. ---> Project.Lib.Utils.ManualException: ERROR: Process TABLE_1: ProcessLoadTable was finished with an error ---> Project.DataLoader.Exceptions.TableLoadException: Load of table TABLE_1 failed ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Teradata.Cleint.Provider.TdException: [TeraGSS Security Library] [115022] Exception occurred in TERAGSS layer. See inner exception for details. ---> Teradata.Net.Security.TdgssException: The token failed the intergrity check. ErrorCode: -2146233088 Severity: Warning Facility: LoadTdgss at Teradata.Net.Security.Cryptogrphy.QopContext.NewUnwrap`

This does not always happen, but it does happen like 90% of the time, usually when the data is really large. So far, by loading small amount of data at a time the jobs work but this is time consuming. I did read up that .NET providers are not stable with Teradata. Not sure how to get this to always work for large data.

Comment: Don't recall .NET provider instability issues. What version of .NET provider? Is your Teradata system using (or configured to allow) TLSv1.2?